# Styling A PHP E-Mail Handler Page?

Tags: php, css, email

I have an HTML form and I also have the PHP Mail Handler file, but what I want to do is style the PHP file, with a design, how do I do this?

http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/thecommonwealth/

If you click on the "Click To Inquire" you will see the form, and it leads to... contact.php on my server.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, looks like it needs javascript.

Comment: @hakre It doesn't LEAD to the contact.php page unless you submit something via the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest way I believe is just to cover your response from contact.php with HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

Some design

<?php echo $myresponse; ?>

Some design

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But what would I do with the PHP code that handles the e-mails being sent out of the server? Instead of just the echos? Do I place those in the header?

Comment: As you wish)) you can process email send before output... and echo smth else if it fails...